# Animation conversion failed: transform for bone not found?

Tags: unity, animation

I'm trying to animate my first humanoid, and the animations in the Standard Assets pack (HumanoidIdle etc) work really well right out of the box. However, when I try to use other fbx files, like those in Unity's "Raw MoCap Data" pack, I get errors.

I import the animations, select one, go to "Edit…" and go to "Rig", select "Humanoid", copy the avatar definition from the character I'm trying to animate (e.g. Robot Kyle), and under "Animations" I will get an error like "Imported file RunBackward conversion failed: Transform 'Left_Thigh_Joint_01' for human bone 'LeftUpperLeg' not found". When I compare the avatar of the character I'm trying to animate with the avatar that comes with the animations, they have the same bones defined, just with different names (which shouldn't matter, right?), so it's not that bones are missing. Using the animation with the default avatar also doesn't work, I get no error but my character goes into the first frame of the animation but then freezes. I've tried this with the standard models Ethan and Robot Kyle to the same effect.

Does anyone know how to handle this import error?

Comment: Names of the bones actually do matter a lot, as a computer can't understand that "UpperLeftLeg" equals "Upper_Left_Leg".

Comment: Right, but what I mean is that the animation shouldn't care about what bones are called when you import it, correct? Or does importing an animation using my model's avatar only work if my avatar's bones are named exactly as the animation is expecting?

Answer (score 1):

The bones in the animation you're importing need to have the exact same name as in the skeleton you're using.

Comment: Thanks! How can I change the names of the bones in the animation, and can I do this within Unity? I'm currently trying to use the animations from Unity's own "raw mocap data", so I didn't make them myself...

Comment: @Cosmo I don't know if unity itself can do it, but you could try asking the blender community at http://blender.stackexchange.com/ if they can help you.